# How to logout user after 5 minutes on minimization of application in android?

Tags: android, service, background

I have an application which consists of user login, I wish to implement a functionality which will log the user out from application after 5 minutes once the user minimizes the application.

I have already tried a code where I am getting a log print on the console when the user minimizes the application or the application is in the background, but how I can log out the user after 5 minutes if he continues to keep the app in background for 5 min long.

```
dependencies {
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
}
```

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
private void onAppBackgrounded() {
    Log.d("MyApp", "App in background");

final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 5 min - logout code


            }
        }, 5000);

}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
private void onAppForegrounded() {
    Log.d("MyApp", "App in foreground");
}
}
```

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ....>
</application>
```

The current code is allowing me to run code in the background, but how I can log out the user after 5 minutes if he continues to keep the app in the background for 5 min long.

Comment: dont think about when in the background, think about checking the amount of time when returning to the foreground. If > 5min then send them back to the login screen or whatever

Comment: @tyczj better idea but he want to identify the amount of time which is taken by minimize operation so it needs to be inside the `onAppBackgrounded`

Comment: @Ashish You can save a timestamp to shared preferences when backgrounding, then when the app is foreground you check the current time. if the diff is > 5 min then logout, you dont need a timer like you suggest

Comment: @tyczj i think the function `onAppForegrounded` starts on App come in foreground which will be the reason to take time to logout.

Comment: @Ashish yes obviously it does, it take milliseconds to do a simple time compare vs having to remember to cancel a timer when the app was resumed in < 5 min time

Comment: @Ashish also your solution would launch the app again showing login screen when the user chose to minimize the app for whatever reason interrupting them from doing whatever they were doing outside of the app